# How to display single product gallery with Timber?

Tags: wordpress-theming, timber

Following the [Timber docs](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/docs/guides/woocommerce.md), the single product page does not display the pictures gallery. How can I do that with Timber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `{{ product|print_r }}`, I have found the answer, considering the `product` context, you can use:

```
{% for id in product.gallery_image_ids %}
    <img src="{{ Image(id).src }}" />
{% endfor %}
```